How to remove [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/_nuxt/@plugin-vuetify/lib/components/VDivider/VDivider.sass"
I am fairly new to nuxt environment and I am trying to understand what causes these errors and how to remove them. These error shows when I execute npm run dev for the first time.

WARN  [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/_nuxt/@plugin-vuetify/lib/components/VApp/VApp.sass"
WARN  [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/_nuxt/@plugin-vuetify/lib/components/VApp/VApp.sass"
WARN  [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/_nuxt/@plugin-vuetify/lib/components/VCard/VCard.sass"
WARN  [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/_nuxt/@plugin-vuetify/lib/components/VCard/VCard.sass"
WARN  [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/_nuxt/@plugin-vuetify/lib/components/VImg/VImg.sass"`

It is worth noting that I am using custom routing on my project and followed the Nuxt documentation on how to implement it. here
Things I've tried:

added the following code on my nuxt.config.ts file

    css: ["vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass"],
    build: {
        transpile: ["vuetify"],
    },
    vite: {
        define: {
            "process.env.DEBUG": false,
        },
    },


used plugin/router.ts instead of doing it in app/router.options.ts
imported vuetify/settings in settings.scss on my project


From my side I had a similar issue with Nuxt 3 and Vuetify. All my message was located inside my server prompt after run npm run dev at time I load a page using some Vuetify components.

The way to solve it to me was located inside the <app-root>/plugins/vuetify.ts
My file was like this
import 'vuetify/styles'
import type { ThemeDefinition } from 'vuetify'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

const impaaktTheme: ThemeDefinition = {
    dark: false,
    colors: {
        primary: '#4fc1b1',
        secondary: '#d53a7c',
        tertiary: '#5b6670',
        accent: '#0076bc',
        error: '#d92e50',
    },
}

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
        theme: {
            defaultTheme: 'impaaktTheme',
            themes: {
                impaaktTheme,
            },
        },
    })
    
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})

And seems this way to inject options inside createVuetify replace the default configuration (at least for server) leading to this warning messages relatively without consequences (in my case) due to the fact my SSR render not need CSS stuff.
But to stop the anoying warning I just re-inject myself components and directives.
import 'vuetify/styles'
import type { ThemeDefinition } from 'vuetify'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

import * as components from 'vuetify/lib/components' // get all components
import * as directives from 'vuetify/lib/directives' // get all directives

const impaaktTheme: ThemeDefinition = {
    dark: false,
    colors: {
        primary: '#4fc1b1',
        secondary: '#d53a7c',
        tertiary: '#5b6670',
        accent: '#0076bc',
        error: '#d92e50',
    },
}

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
        theme: {
            defaultTheme: 'impaaktTheme',
            themes: {
                impaaktTheme,
            },
        },
        components, // re-inject components manually
        directives, // re-inject directives manually
    })
    
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})

